# Javascript popup Messagebox not working when we use Response.Redirect on ASP.NET Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-3.5

I have update button and after saving the record to database, I am displaying popup Msg using Javascript as below.

When i don't use Response.Redirect, Popup is working fine.
But when i use Response.Redirect, Popup is not displaying.

Anybody faced the same issue. Please throw some light.

Appreciate your help.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
                this,
                typeof(string),
                "popup",
                "alert('Thank you for visiting the MedInfo website. Your request has been submitted.');",
                true);
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

Comment: I what way you are updating the values in the table ? i mean POSTBACK or AJAX ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a js function , in function show message then navigate to the page

Server side

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "key", "ShowMessage()", true);
```

JS

```
function ShowMessage()
{
      alert('your message');
      window.location.href='default.aspx';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The very reason you don't see the message is that you navigate from this page, so the page with this script injected in it never gets rendered.

Comment: Then, what is the resolution? How can i display the message?

Comment: Don't think you can achieve that using this method. I would use Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this, typeof(string), "popup", "alert('Thank you for visiting the MedInfo website. Your request has been submitted.');", true); on your page load instead, so it would run when you click your button

Answer (score 2):

Response.Redirect transfers the control to another page, and your script is loaded in the current page.

See **[Response.Redirect Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309.aspx)**

Remove the response.redirect method and then change the scriptmanager. Remove the alert message and instead call a javascript function. Inside the function you can show the alert message and then on the next line write

```
document.location = "Default.aspx";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
                this,
                typeof(string),
                "popup",
                "alert('Thank you for visiting the MedInfo website. Your request has been submitted.')" + "location.href='Default.aspx';",true);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier, `Response.Redirect` interrupt current page execution and transfers control to another page. If you want to show message box after redirect, register your javascript code in Page_Load event handler routine of page to which you are redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a server side, try doing it in the client side. Add `window.top.location ="Default.aspx"` to your javascript code